# Flutter - How do I Show Images , after every 5 items?

Tags: flutter

I have list of images.
and List of Items.

```
List<String> images = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3'];
List<String> text = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

I am using `ListView` Builder,

Code:

```
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: text.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var item = text[index];
            return Column(
              children: [
               ((index + 1) % 6 == 0) ?
                  Text("image")
                :
                  Text('text')
              ],
            );
          }),
```

But the problem is , "text" every 5th item get replaced to "image" ...

please help me.

Comment: Do mean `text` as List item and should it be placed as row/column.

Comment: first of all you edit your parsing data. this is not good method with different Arrays. you have to make just one array. if you make an `Array` like `[{text: "a", image: "imageUrl"}, {text: "b", image: "imageUrl1"}]`, it gonna perfect to parse your datas to interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make by using 'ListView.separated' widget.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        child: _buildBody(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    List images = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3'];
    List text = [
      'a',
      'b',
      'c',
      'd',
      'e',
      'f',
      'g',
      'h',
      'i',
      'j',
      'k',
      'l',
      'm',
      'n'
    ];

   

    return ListView.separated(
      itemCount: text.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
        if ((index + 1) % 5 == 0) {
          return Text(images[(index) ~/ 5]);
        } else {
          return Container();
        }
      },
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text(text[index]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListView.separated`

```
    List images = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3'];
    List texts = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4'];
    int imageIndex = 0;

    return ListView.separated(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
        child: Text('${texts[index]}'),
      ),
      separatorBuilder: (context, _) => Container(
        child: Text('${images[imageIndex++]}'),
      ),
      itemCount: texts.length,
    );
```

Remember that the separator length should be exactly one less than the itemBuilder length. in this case `images.length() == texts.length()-1`